# Django template POST + Multiple field

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-2.x, шаблоны

Есть такой кусок шаблона:

```
{% for item in items %}
    <form method="post" action="update">
    {% csrf_token %}
  ........................
          <select multiple = 'multiple' style='height: 100%;' name = 'subitems'>
                {% for subitem in item.5 %}
                     <option value="{{ subitem.0 }}" selected="True">{{ subitem.1 }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </label><br>
        </p>
  <p><input type="submit" ></p>
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

Во view читаю так:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
   ......................
    genres = request.POST.get('subitems')
```

В результате читает только последнее значение из subitems. 
Как прочитать все?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*get* берет только одно значение, нужно пользоваться *getlist*.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
   ......................
    genres = request.POST.getlist('subitems')
```